# How to prepare ics file for google calendar

Tags: csv, calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I was trying to prepare .ics file compatible with google calendar.
All data that i have was a bit messy so first I prepared .csv file using MSexcel and then this site: http://manas.tungare.name/software/csv-to-ical/

After couple tries it parsed file
Now when i try to add it do google calendar is says that it processed 324 events and imported one.
I've tried with only 5 events and it only adds the last one.

here is short example:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//CSV to iCal Convertor//Manas Tungare, manas.tungare.name//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
X-WR-CALNAME;VALUE=TEXT:test1f
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Programowanie serwerów baz danych
DESCRIPTION:wykład dr inż. NAME
DTSTAMP:20160222T081500
DTSTART:20160222T081500
DTEND:20160222T100000
LOCATION:WI WI1-200
UID:mail@gmail.com
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Metody kompilacji
DESCRIPTION:laboratorium dr inż. NAME
DTSTAMP:20160222T101500
DTSTART:20160222T101500
DTEND:20160222T120000
LOCATION:WI WI1-308
UID:mail@gmail.com
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Programowanie w językach skryptowych
DESCRIPTION:wykład mgr inż. NAME
DTSTAMP:20160223T121500
DTSTART:20160223T121500
DTEND:20160223T140000
LOCATION:WI WI2-227
UID:mail@gmail.com
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Programowanie w języku Java
DESCRIPTION:wykład dr inż. NAME
DTSTAMP:20160223T161500
DTSTART:20160223T161500
DTEND:20160223T180000
LOCATION:WI WI2-227
UID:mail@gmail.com
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Metody kompilacji
DESCRIPTION:wykład prof.dr hab.inż. NAME
DTSTAMP:20160224T101500
DTSTART:20160224T101500
DTEND:20160224T120000
LOCATION:WI WI2-126
UID:mail@gmail.com
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I don't know what still might be wrong with it.
Could somebody point me out my mistake?
Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each event's `UID` property must be unique.